# How to trackDown EXC_BAD_ACESS

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i m parsing a json in table view.clicking the tableview navigates to nextview.after few clicks the app gets crashed.I have set NSZombieEnabled in my environmental variable and i got this message in my console`*** -[NSCFString isEqual:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1f31d0`
how to trace back which variable exactly i m getting the leak would be great if you guys could help me out.

Comment: wouldn't it take you to the crashing line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try enabling the exception breakpoint? You can try tracking that zombie on instruments, the long way:

1. Run your app on Intruments.
2. In instruments, select Object allocations tool(automatically selected if you select leaks tool).
3. Click on the little "i" on top left, within the Allocations tool.
4. Select "Enable NSZombie detection".
5. Press the record button and let your app run.
6. Go through the execution of the app untill it crashes. As soon as there is a crash, you'd see a pop up saying that there was a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Click on the little -> on the pop up to see the object that has turned into a zombie and the line of code responsible.

Comment: i was able to put a check mark in NSZombieEnabled the first time.but when i run the app second time i m not able to find the NSZombieEnabled option in the Allocations tab when i click the "i".if i m to record when the app crashes i m not getting the pop out could u help me out

Comment: What Xcode version are you using? Are you testing on device or a simulator(You wouldn't get the NSZombieEnabled option on device)?

Comment: im using xcode 4.2..i was testing it on device...i ll let u know if it works

Comment: dat totally worked in simulator. i m having little trouble i was able to find the object that caused the leak and rectified it..when i again tested .there was another leak and got the popup.when it clicked i m not able to get the variable or the object dat is responsible cud u help me out

Comment: Since you have made code changes, I would recommend doing the profiling after cleaning and building your code and removing the app from simulator before starting again.